# How to initialize instance field in a constructor to another object in java?

Tags: java, constructor

I have two classes in Java:

```
public class DeckOfCards {
    private ArrayList<Card> deck;
    private int currentCard;

    public DeckOfCards() {
      this.deck = new ArrayList<>();
      this.currentCard = 0; // first Card dealt will be deck[0]
   }
}
```

and

```
public class CardPlayer {
    private enum PLAYER_TYPE {PERSON, COMPUTER};
    private PLAYER_TYPE player;
    private DeckOfCards deck;
    private int currentSum;

    public CardPlayer(int playerType) {
        this.player = PLAYER_TYPE.PERSON;
        this.deck = initializeDeckField();
    }

    private static final DeckOfCards initializeDeckField() {
        DeckOfCards d = new DeckOfCards();
        return d;
    }
}
```

One of the fields of `CardPlayer` object is a `DeckOfCards` object. I was wondering if there's some way to use `DeckOfCards` constructor directly inside the `CardPlayer` constructor in order to initialize the `deck` field of `CardPlayer`.

So far the only solution I found is to use another function to do this. Is there any better way or more correct way?

Comment: You can just use `this.deck = new DeckOfCards();` ; see that you are doing that with `deck` in `DeckOfCards`

Comment: If you use an IDE, select `initializeDeckField()` and display the refactoring operations related to. You should have something as "inline".

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `CardPlayer` have a `DeckOfCards` so why not inherit the player from the deck.

```java
public class CardPlayer extends DeckOfCards
```

And when you instantiate a player you also create his associated deck.

```java
public CardPlayer(int playerType) {
    super();
    this.player = PLAYER_TYPE.PERSON;
    this.deck = initializeDeckField();
}
```